# Last character of a multibyte string

Tags: multibyte

One of the things I often need to do when handling a multibyte string is deleting its last character. How do I locate this last character so I can chop it off using normal byte operations, preferably with as few reads as possible?

Note that this question is intended to work for *most*, if not *all*, multibyte encodings. The answer for self-synchonizing encodings like UTF-8 is trivial, as you can just go right-to-left in the bytestring for a start marker.

Answer (score 0):

The answer will be written in C, with POSIX multibyte functions. The said functions are also found on Windows. Assume that the bytestring ends at `len` and is well-formed up to the point; assume appropriate `setlocale` calls. Porting to `mbrlen` is left as an exercise for the reader.

#### The naive solution

The obviously correct solution involves parsing the encoding "as intended", going from left-to-right.

```
ssize_t index_of_last_char_left(const char *c, size_t len) {
  size_t pos = 0;
  size_t next = 1;
  mblen(NULL, 0);

  while (pos < len - 1) {
    next = mblen(c + pos, len - pos);
    if (next == -1)  // Invalid input
      return pos;
    pos += next;
  }

  return pos - next;
}
```

Deleting multiple characters like this will cause an "accidentally quadratic" situation; memorizing of intermediate positions will help, but additional management is required.

#### The right-to-left solution

As I mentioned in the question, for self-synchonizing encodings the only thing to do is to look for a start marker. But what breaks with the ones that don't self-synchonize?

- The one-or-two-byte [EUC encodings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Unix_Code) have both bytes of the two-byte sequence higher than `0x7f`, and there's almost no differentiating between start and continuation bytes. For that we can check for `mblen(pos) == bytes_left` since we know the string is well-formed.
- The Big5, GBK, and GB10830 encodings also allow a continuation byte in the ASCII range, so a lookbehind is mandatory.

With that cleared out (and assuming the bytestring up to `len` is well-formed), we can have:

```
// As much as CJK encodings do. I don't have time to see if it works for UTF-1.
#define MAX_MB_LEN 4

ssize_t index_of_last_char_right(const char *c, size_t len) {
  ssize_t pos = len - 1;
  bool last = true;
  bool last_is_okay = false;
  assert(!mblen(NULL, 0));   // No, we really cannot handle shift states.

  for (; pos >= 0 && pos >= len - 2 - MAX_MB_LEN; pos--) {
    int next = mblen(c + pos, len - pos);
    bool okay = (next > 0) && (next == len - pos - 1);
    if (last) {
      last_is_okay = okay;
      last = false;
    } else if (okay)
      return pos;
  }

  return last_is_okay ? len - 1 : -1;
}
```

(You should be able to find the last good char of a malformed string by `(next > 0) && (next <= len - pos - 1)`. But don't return that when the last byte is okay!)

#### What's the point of this?

The code sample above is for the idealist who does not want to write just a "UTF-8 support" but a "locale support" based on the C library. There might not have a point for this at all in 2021 :)